# Call method on multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

Let's say I have a method like so:

```
public class ColoredPoint {

    private final Color color; 
    private final int x;
    private final int y;    

    public ColoredPoint(int x, int y, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    } 

    public ColoredPoint(int x, int y, int color) {
        this(x,y, new Color(color));
    }  

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Then I populate a **single dimension array** with some data like so for example:

```
public class DemoInput {
final static ColoredPoint[] test2 = new ColoredPoint[]
{ new ColoredPoint( 208, 324, -1 )
, new ColoredPoint( 154, 313, -1 )
, new ColoredPoint( 288, 316, -1 )
, new ColoredPoint( 312, 296, -1 )
}
```

How can I figure out the biggest x in the array? I have a method to get x from the ColoredPoint so this should be easy, right?

I know I can use a for-loop for this. I just don't now to to get the x from the ColoredPoint inside the array.

I want the x value of a ColoredPoint in the array called test2 in the class DemoInput so I thought:

```
DemoInput.test2.ColoredPoint.getX[i]
```

would do the trick but that doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out? Also, how would it work for a **multidimensional array**, like such:

```
allTests = new ColoredPoint[][]
  { test1
  , test2
 };
```

Comment: There are many ways to get biggest `x` but `for loop` can be the simplest approach. But at least I want to see what your `for loop` code looks like.

Comment: Sure. I would do it like this:

`int biggestx = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<DemoInput.test1.length;i++) {
      if (DemoInput.test1[i].getX()>biggestx) {
        biggestx = DemoInput.test1[i].getX();
      }`

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: Yes but just because of @Mureinik. I didn't know the correct syntax before.

Comment: Do you know why `for (int i : DemoInput.test1)`wont work?

Comment: Because `DemoInput.test1` references `ColorPoint`

Comment: Im trying to understand this special way of writing a for loop. So could you elaborate a bit? What would I need to change in order for it to work?

Comment: The right way is `for (ColorPoint i : DemoInput.test1)`

Comment: I think you meant `for (ColoredPoint i : DemoInput.test1)`. This works, many thanks! However, now the statements inside the loop dont work anymore, since *"ColoredPoint cannot be converted to int"*. How would you fix that?

Comment: `int biggestx = 0; for (ColoredPoint i : DemoInput.test1) if (biggestx < i.getX() ) biggestx = i.getX();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first get a `ColoredPoint` element from the array (using the `[]` operator), and then call the `getX()` method on it:

```
x = DemoInput.test2[i].getX()
// Here -----------^
```

The same logic applies for a 2D array - using the `[]` operator will return a `1D` array, on which you'll need to use the `[]` operator in order to get a `ColoredPoint` element:

```
x = DemoInput.allTests[i][j].getX()
// Here --------------^
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much :) I messed around with the order before but I forgot the () after the getX.

Answer (score 1):

Java streams are pretty useful for finding things like largest and smallest:

```
Arrays.stream(test2).mapToInt(ColoredPoint::getX).max();
```

Multi-dimensional is slightly less elegant:

```
Arrays.stream(allTests).map(Arrays::stream)
    .flatMapToInt(test -> test.mapToInt(ColoredPoint::getX)).max();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible implementation

```
public class ColoredPoint implements Comparable<ColoredPoint> {
    private final Color color;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public ColoredPoint(int x, int y, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public ColoredPoint(int x, int y, int color) {
        this(x, y, new Color(color));
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ColoredPoint o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.x, o.x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColoredPoint[] test2 = new ColoredPoint[]{new ColoredPoint(208, 324, -1)
            , new ColoredPoint(154, 313, -1)
            , new ColoredPoint(288, 316, -1)
            , new ColoredPoint(312, 296, -1)
        };

        Optional<ColoredPoint> maxColor = Arrays.stream(test2).max(ColoredPoint::compareTo);
        maxColor.ifPresent(coloredPoint -> System.out.println("Max X = " + coloredPoint.getX()));
    }
}
```

This is a Java 8 compatible solution.

**Hope this helps!**